# Status bar disappears after unlocking with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app with *Status Bar initially hidden: YES* and

```
NavigationView {
}
.statusBar(hidden: true)
```

When the app starts, the bar is not visible but its space is not occupied (so it looks like additional padding from top). But when I lock/unlock the phone this padding disappears thus moving the whole app closer to the top.

Any suggestions what's causing it?

Comment: Would you show code of this custom modifier?

Comment: [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful along with the environment info (phone vs simulator, version, ...).

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

[image]

Just tested it with the following view and it really jumps up after you lock/unlock the screen. Try to take a screenshot and it jumps up as well (found this accidentally when I was taking screenshots for the answer).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Color.green
                .navigationBarTitle("No status bar")
        }
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}
```

### Workaround

Just add the line marked in the code below.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Color.green
                .navigationBarTitle("No status bar")
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // <-------
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}
```

IMHO it should work without this line, but it doesn't apparently. This problem is here even if I set (`Info.plist`):

- `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES`
- `UIStatusBarHidden` to `YES`

Or if I hide status bar directly on the `ContentView` (`SceneDelegate`):

- `let contentView = ContentView().statusBar(hidden: true)`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, with edgesIgnoringSafeArea the behaviour is now reversed. At the program start the bar is not present, after unlocking the phone it reappears.

Comment: You're right. Still researching it, so far I've found that the `safeAreaInsets.top` (`GeometryProxy`) contains wrong value. Status bar is hidden (initially in `Info.plist` & on `NavigationView`), but the `top` contains `20`. Whenever I lock/unlock, take a screenshot, ... `top` contains `0` - the correct one. This is the reason why it jumps, but no reliable fix/workaround yet.